# Running a Jar twice

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

is it possible to run a Jar twice?

e.g. consider a Jar which has 2 entry points. can I run them twice simultaneously, each time with an entry, **without any kind of weird (like memory) problem**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jar/application does not prevent a second start - yes
If you start your application within different jvm's they are different processes which (usually) have no shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's fine. You can run one jar files multiple times, like starting tomcat server twice, which is a pretty common setup. In my understanding, there is no memory leaking problem at all. On the contrary, modern JRE can enable class-sharing among multiple process, which can save considerable memory.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i dont think java interpreter alone understands multiple entry points. But you can write an application which understands this and launch the correct Main-class.

Secondly, even if java inrterpreter knew to launch multiple entry points it should be launching each in a separate JVM making it safe.